# Create a macro to return a reify (java Interface) but with a supplied quoted expression in clojure

Tags: clojure

What I am trying to achieve is to implement an abstract class with reify inside a macro, but the expressions that should return on expansion time would be supplied to the macro quoted:

```
(defmacro a-printable
[body]
`(reify Printable
 (print [this g# pf# page#]
  (if (= page# 0)
   (do
    ~body ;; the supplied part
    (Printable/PAGE_EXISTS))
   (Printable/NO_SUCH_PAGE)))

(def exp '(do (.translate g (.getImageableX pf) (.getImageableY pf))
              (.drawString g "foo" 10 10))) ;; the form to pass
(a-printable exp)
```

The proplem is that in the expression I pass, I want to use the automatic generated vars defined inside the macro and inside reify `g#, pf#`.
I tried to add the quoted expression with  `(ns-resolve *ns* g)` `(ns-resolve *ns* pf)` but with no lack, I am not sure that is being resolved inside the macro.
The `g` is `java.awt.Graphics` which is an abstract class and the `pf` is `java.awt.print.PageFormat`, which is normal class with constructor.
Does anyone has any idea how to achieve that, or turn me to the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the trick is that if you don't want namespaced symbols in a macro, you can prefix them with `~'`, e.g. `~'g`. Then I did the following other modifications to your macro:

1. Prefix the `body` parameter with `&` to make it variable length.
2. Splice the body into the macro
3. Remove the parenthesis around `(Printable/PAGE_EXISTS)` and `(Printable/NO_SUCH_PAGE)`: Those are static variable values that you want to return, not function calls.

This is what the fixed macro looks like:

```
(defmacro a-printable
  [& body]
  `(reify Printable
     (print [~'this ~'g ~'pf ~'page]
       (if (= ~'page 0)
         (do
           ~@body ;; Splice it!
           Printable/PAGE_EXISTS)
         Printable/NO_SUCH_PAGE))))
```

And this is how you create an instance. Note that I do not need to wrap the argument to the macro with `do`:

```
(def p (a-printable
        (.translate g (.getImageableX pf) (.getImageableY pf))
        (.drawString g "foo" 10 10)))
```

A note however: I am not sure it is a good practice to introduce new symbols, such as `pf` and `g`, but I cannot find the reference mentioning why that would be a bad practice. There are ways of achieving similar things to what is being asked in this question without resorting to macros. The version that *does not* use macros is not much longer:

```
(defn a-printable-fn [body-fn]
  (reify Printable
    (print [this g pf page]
      (if (= ~'page 0)
        (do
          (body-fn this g pf page)
          Printable/PAGE_EXISTS)
        Printable/NO_SUCH_PAGE))))


(def p (a-printable-fn
        (fn [this g pf page]
          (.translate g (.getImageableX pf) (.getImageableY pf))
          (.drawString g "foo" 10 10))))
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your time to answer my question. Secondly, I  would like to ask, why I should prefer the function version, I thought that, because of the fact I want to pass quoted expressions macros would be the way I should do it. It would be bad practice in general, the use of macros when I can do the same with functions?